# How to do batching with TensorFlow Lite?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a custom CNN model, and I have converted it to .tflite format and deployed it on my Android app. However, I can't figure out how to do batching while inference with tensorflow lite.

From this Google [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models), it seems you have to set the input format of your model. However, this doc is using a code example with Firebase API, which I'm not planning on using.

To be more specific:

I want to inference multiple 100x100x3 images at once, so the input size is **N**x100x100x3.

Question:

How to do this with TF lite?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just call the `resizeInput` API (Java) or `ResizeInputTensor` API (if you're using C++).

For example, in Java:

```
interpreter.resizeInput(tensor_index, [num_batch, 100, 100, 3]);
```

Let us know if you have any problem batching in TensorFlow lite.

Comment: Don't forget to call `allocate_tensors()` afterwards! My kernel was crashing with the python API until i realized this.

Comment: In regard to the previous command, `allocate_tensors()` is not a public method in the Java API.  Rather, it is called automatically by the underlying framework as needed.

Comment: **Python** :`interpreter.resize_tensor_input(tensor_index, [num_batch, 100, 100, 3])`

Do run the command : `interpreter.allocate_tensors()` for the above things to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, in Java that explains more about inference tflite models with different batch size:

```
    // First get the input shape of the interpreter, this will give you smth like this [1, 300, 300, 3]
    int[] inputs = interpreter.getInputTensor(0).shape();
    // The first element of above array represents batch size, so we change that
    inputs[0] = 4 // 4 is batch size in this case
    // update interpreter with new input size
    interpreter.resizeInput(0, inputs);
```

One other important thing is how you prepare the input and output of interpreter, input data will be smth like this (extra attention to the "IMPORTANT" comment):

```
    int numBytesPerChannel;
    if (isQuantized) {
      numBytesPerChannel = 1; // Quantized
    } else {
      numBytesPerChannel = 4; // Floating point
    }
    imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(batchSize * inputWidth * inputHeight * 3 * numBytesPerChannel);
    imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    ........
    // Here you add the data from bitmap into the ByteBuffer (imgData)
    // IMPORTANT: make sure that you write all the data into the same ByteBuffer (in our case imgData)
    ........
    Object[] inputArray = {imgData};
    Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
    // add your output here, I am adding [4][1][1][1024] as example, 4 is batch size
    outputMap.put(0, new float[4][1][1][1024]);
    // and then run the tflite interpreter
    interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
```