# TensorFlow Lite: Batching with Mobilenet_V2

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I want to do batching with Mobilenet_V2_1.0_224 in TensorFlow Lite .

I tried this answer [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783747/how-to-do-batching-with-tensorflow-lite/53125376#53125376](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783747/how-to-do-batching-with-tensorflow-lite/53125376#53125376)), but this works only for Inception_V4.

When I try to use a batch size >1 (in this case batch_size 2) for Mobilenet i get the following error:

```
  ComposedException 1 :
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Internal error: Cannot allocate memory for the interpreter: tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:68 num_input_elements != num_output_elements (2002 != 1001)Node 64 failed to prepare.

    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.allocateTensors(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:118)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:168)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:145)
```

Edit:
This is the tflite code resulting in this error:

```
    DIM_BATCH_SIZE = 4
    var tfliteOptions: Interpreter.Options = Interpreter.Options()
    tfliteOptions.setUseNNAPI(true)
    var interpreter = Interpreter(loadModelFile(assetManager, "mobilenet_v2_1.0_224.tflite")!!, tfliteOptions)    
    interpreter!!.resizeInput(0,intArrayOf(DIM_BATCH_SIZE,224,224,3))

    interpreter!!.run(imgData, labelProb)
```

imgData is a ByteBuffer containing the preprocessed images, labelProb the FloatArray for the predictions.

Comment: Please provide your code that is resulting in this error.

Comment: @NupurGarg I edited the post

Comment: Hey @rossp did you manage to find a solution to this error?

Comment: @harshithdwivedi No, sadly not.

Comment: Does this answer's your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783747/how-to-do-batching-with-tensorflow-lite?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: As mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76507051/13566128 , you should add the data in the first element of ByteBuffer array