# Android: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input Tensor index: 1

Tags: java, android, tensor, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to interpret multiple input outputs by using method of **org.tensorflow.lite** (doc link https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference) which is given below :

```
interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, map_of_indices_to_outputs);
```

while I am passing a single value in the input-output array. its working fine and getting the proper output. ***But in case of more than 1 input-output values getting error.***

*Code with single item array:*

```
 List<ByteBuffer> byteBuffer = new ArrayList<>() ;
 byteBuffer.add(convertBitmapToByteBufferOld(bitmap));
 Map<Integer, Object> outputs = new HashMap<>();
 byte[][] result1 = new byte[1][labelList.size()];
 outputs.put(0, result1);
 interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(byteBuffer.toArray(), outputs);
```

***Output:*** working fine getting ML process result.

*Code with multiple input-output arrays is given below:*

```
 List<ByteBuffer> byteBuffer = new ArrayList<>() ;
 byteBuffer.add(convertBitmapToByteBufferOld(bitmap1));
 byteBuffer.add(convertBitmapToByteBufferOld(bitmap2));
 Map<Integer, Object> outputs = new HashMap<>();
 byte[][] result1 = new byte[1][labelList.size()];
 byte[][] result2 = new byte[1][labelList.size()];
 outputs.put(0, result1);
 outputs.put(1, result2);
 interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(byteBuffer.toArray(), outputs);
```

***Error:***

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input Tensor index: 1
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.getInputTensor(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:269)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:136)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:314)
        at com.amitshekhar.tflite.TensorFlowImageClassifier.recognizeImage(TensorFlowImageClassifier.java:88)
```

*It would be great if anyone resolves my problem. Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have tested and tried to run the model with different batch size, you should add the bitmap data in first element of `byteBuffer` array, and not add new element in `byteBuffer` list.
I cannot find anything official from tensorflow lite but this is how I managed to solve this.
If you want to check an example check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76507845/13566128).